# JSON, JAXB, Formatting issues

Tags: java, javascript, rest, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I am have a trouble with the data format problem. I have a simple JaxB Class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="")
public class MyProgressResponse {
    private int weight;
    private long date;
    /**
     * Weight is treated as a Y Axis.
     * @return
     */
    @XmlElement(name="y")
    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    /**
     * This is a UTC format of a time.
     * value is a number of milliseconds between a specified date and midnight January 1 1970
     * This is also treated as a X-Axis
     * @return 
     */
    @XmlElement(name="x")
    public long getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

And I want the REST service that fill that returns the data. like this

```
@GET
@Path("/my")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MyProgressResponse[] getProgressResponse(){
    // Get the data from DB
    // Here the getDate will give me List<MyProgressResponse>
    return getData().toArray(new MyProgressResponse[0]);
}
```

Now the JSON that I receive is like

```
[
 {
   {
     "x": 1335499200000,
     "y": 85
   }
 },
 {
   {
     "x": 1334894400000,
     "y": 84
   }
 },
 ....
]
```

But my requirement is to get the that does not have one extra block `{ }`.

```
[
   {
     "x": 1335499200000,
     "y": 85
   },
   {
     "x": 1334894400000,
     "y": 84
   },
   ....
]
```

I want to use this in a HighChart. I can format the data in JS after i receive the data but it will get extra time and I dont want that.

Can anyone can help me in formatting the data

Thanks,

Talha Ahmed Khan

Comment: How does the output look if you return it as XML instead of JSON?

Comment: Could you publish your `MyProgressResponse` class? JSON output you've provided is really weird, and for me it looks like it's connected with `MyProgressResponse` class inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your return type of the method to ArrayList :

```
@GET @Path("/my") 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public ArrayList<MyProgressResponse> getProgressResponse(){     
// Get the data from DB     
// Here the getDate will give me List<MyProgressResponse>

ArrayList<MyProgressResponse> response=(ArrayList<MyProgressResponse>) getData();

return response; 
}
```

Also make your bean class implement Serializable.

Comment: There is no change after converting it to `List`